# How to implement an horizontal image gallery in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to implement an image gallery with horizontal scroll. The amounts of items in the gallery can be very high depending on users.

I've tried adding Items to a FlipView:

```
<FlipView>
    <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
    <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
    <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
</FlipView>
```

The behavior is correct but since the image gallery can have a large amounts of images, the [Guidelines for flip view controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh850405.aspx) say that

```
Don't use a flip view control for large collections. 
The repetitive motion of flipping through each item becomes tedious for users
```

Flipping though each item is exactly what I want, but I imagine it could be problematic if I have a FlipView with 1000 items.

How can I implement this correctly?

Complete answer will be awarded with a bounty

Comment: If you want to ignore the guidelines then that is up to you, it only suggests not doing it because it will become irritating. Or do you just want a long film strip of items that you can scroll/swipe through?

Comment: I want to implement a gallery with the same behavior than the Photos app. Where I can explore my camera photos swiping across the gallery allowing pan and zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you considered `ISupportIncrementalLoading`? I never implement it in `FlipView`, but it works fine for `ListView` and they both have same behavior with collection of items in `ItemSource`. [Here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=226854) is you can look at sample of implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar app for the Windows Store a while ago (pre universal apps) and a phone version is not very different. To implement the best user experience, you should have two controls like a GridView and a FlipView that the user can switch between. For the GridView you should implement ISupportIncremental loading so you can load new thumbnails in groups. For the FlipView I would just listen to the SelectionChanged event and preload one or two more images in the direction of the flip (and unload the same number of images from the other end of the list). It is also a good idea to show a progress ring while the image is loading in case they have a slow connection.